# glyphicons button with Bootstrap 3.3.7

Tags: jquery, file-upload, blueimp

I am using a current bootstrap version from the CDN. If I replace

```
<Link rel="stylesheet" href="// netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

by

```
<Link rel="stylesheet" href="// maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

then the glyphicons on the buttons are no longer displayed.

Comment: Have you tried this way: `"https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css"` removing space and adding https:?